# Android: integer from xml resource

Tags: android, android-resources

How do I have to modify my XML resources, or what XML file do I have to create, to access integer values in the same way you access string values with `R.string.some_string_resource` ?

For example, in the code I want to say:

```
ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressBar.setMax(getInteger(R.integer.maximum));
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it would look like this:

1. **Create an xml resources file in the folder `/res/values/` called integers.xml.**

   You are free to give it any name as you want, but choose one that is obvious.
2. **In that resources file, create your integer values.**

   Your file then looks something like that:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>    
       <integer name="maximum">100</integer>
       ...

   </resources>
   ```
3. **Reference the integer value in the Java code like this:**

   It's a bit different from the `getString()`, you have to take a little detour.

   ```
   ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
   int max = getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.maximum);
   progressBar.setMax(max);
   ```

Comment: i like your answer , very nice

Comment: I want to have 0.5 value for integer to use in different layout, would you guide me how to do it?

Comment: That's a double value, not an integer. Maybe you ask that in a separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Terry So is this the preferred method to use Integers in android, I usually hard code it in the code itself. What is your reccomendation?

Comment: @capt.swag Usually you hardcode integers as constants in the code in each class as appropriate. But if you need to have different constants for different layouts (ie number of columns for a grid) then you will use XML files to adapt that constant to various widths of the screen. Hope that helps

Comment: can i use that integer value directly in XML ?

Comment: @capt.swag yes, that's the preferred method

Comment: In Kotlin, reference the integer with `resources.getInteger(R.integer.maximum)`

Answer (score 10):

You must add the integers.xml file to your project

[image]

and then

[image]

and in integers.xml add this

```
<integer name="maximum">5</integer>
```