# SharedPreferences getResources().getInteger()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Android's documentation on [SharedPrefererences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) has this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
```

I searched online and most of the usage involving getResources().getInteger all use R.integer instead of R.string.

Is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: use your R not the default android one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getInteger()` returns the value of an [integer resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer), which is denoted by an `R.integer` value in Java. `R.string` values are for [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

The `SharedPreferences` training guide that you point to has it wrong. I have filed [an issue for that typo](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188473), which will get fixed sometime before the next ice age, if we're lucky.

Comment: Thanks but why do most posts I see use R.integer instead of R.string within getInteger? This is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297522/android-integer-from-xml-resource

Comment: Do you think there's a reason why they decided to use a string resource for an integer value in the docs then?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke: Ah, now I understand the concern. That's a typo in the docs.