# Android SharedPreferences exception in getInt

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use **SharedPreferences** and I stumbled in a probably stupid error of mine. This's my code (**MainActivity** class):

```
private Boolean checkSSID;
private String connectionSSID;
private int leftPort;
private int rightPort;
private int LLUPort;
private int localUDPPort;
private String platformIPAddrStr;
```

At bottom of **onCreate()** method:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

SharedPreferences sharedPref =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

checkSSID = sharedPref.getBoolean
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_CHECK_SSID, false);

connectionSSID = sharedPref.getString
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_CONNECTION_SSID, "\"bulldog\"");

leftPort = sharedPref.getInt
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_LEFT_UDP_PORT, 4001);

rightPort = sharedPref.getInt
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_RIGHT_UDP_PORT, 4002);

LLUPort = sharedPref.getInt
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_LLU_UDP_PORT, 8888);

localUDPPort = sharedPref.getInt
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_LOCAL_UDP_PORT, 5555);

platformType = sharedPref.getInt
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PLATFORM_TYPE,0);
```

at the first **getInt()** call the app crash with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.xxx/it.xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The PreferenceScreen layout:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="checkSSID"
        android:summary="@string/checkSSID_summary"
        android:title="@string/checkSSID_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="bulldog"
        android:key="connectionSSID"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/LLUUDPPort_summary"
        android:title="@string/LLUUDPPort_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="192.168.1.40"
        android:key="platformIPAddr"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/PlatformIPAddr_summary"
        android:title="@string/PlatformIPAddr_title" />
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/PlatformType_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/PlatformType_values"
        android:key="platformType"
        android:summary="@string/PlatformType_summary"
        android:title="@string/PlatformType_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="4001"
        android:key="leftBankUDPPort"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/LeftBankUDPPort_summary"
        android:title="@string/LeftBankUDPPort_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="4002"
        android:key="rightBankUDPPort"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/RightBankUDPPort_summary"
        android:title="@string/RightBankUDPPort_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="8888"
        android:key="LLUUDPPort"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/LLUUDPPort_summary"
        android:title="@string/LLUUDPPort_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="5555"
        android:key="localUDPPort"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/localUDPPort_summary"
        android:title="@string/localUDPPort_title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In **SettingsActivity** I declared all the public strings used to recall preferences key .. i.e.:

```
public static final String
        KEY_PREF_CHECK_SSID = "checkSSID";
```

Where did I fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditTextPreference` returns `String` values, like `ListPreference`. You need to convert every value extracted from shared preferences from `String` to `int`. For example:

```
platformType  = Integer.valueOf(sharedPref.getString
        (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_PLATFORM_TYPE,"0"));
```

Comment: I got errors even on leftPort ... not only on this one... this doesn't fix everything (but it's welcome).

Comment: EditTextPreferences return String, like ListPreferences. Every field that you are trying to extract, is a string. I modified the answer, just to be more clear.

Comment: Looks like this's the solution  ... thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your int values like this

```
public static final int
        KEY_PREF_LEFT_UDP_PORT = 1000;
```

Comment: uh well no... KEY_PREF_LEFT_UDP_PORT  and other final variables defined in SettingsActivity are just reminder for 'key' values in preferences.xml...

Answer (score 0):

Loading Preferences from XML ressources can only deal with strings (as far as I know). In your scenario this is the @string:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkSSID"
    android:summary="@string/checkSSID_summary"
    android:title="@string/checkSSID_title" />
```

Hence I don't know the use case for the other methods like *getInt*, but I also ended up loading it as string and then parsing/casting it to the required type like describe by @xcesco.

Comment: oh right, my bad. Did you try putting the *int*s into a distinct integer resource xml as described here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297522/android-integer-from-xml-resource

Comment: yes I know but as you can read in xcesco answer the terminal problem is the TextView that will only output String objects

Answer (score 0):

looks like all the keys stored in shared preferences are strings , try to load them all as strings then parse the ones you need as integer.
like this :

```
String leftPort_string = sharedPref.getString
    (SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_LEFT_UDP_PORT,"4001");

leftPort=Integer.parseInt(leftPort_string);
```