# How to set R.string.resource_name in this case

Tags: java, android, r, string

I have a code like this

```
if(POS>=5){
    Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this,R.string.last,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else {
     POS += 1;
     fillDetails(POS);
 }
```

I want to get this "5" in `if(POS>=5)` from `strings.xml`

In `strings.xml` I have

```
<string name="lastarticle">5</string>
```

I have tried these

```
if(POS>=R.string.lastaricle)

if(POS>=getString(R.string.lastaricle))

if(POS>=getResources().getString(R.string.mess_1))

if(POS>=this.getString(R.string.resource_name))

if(POS>=@string/lastarticle)
```

but none of them worked. I think I miss something but I don't know what it is?

Comment: Your can do whats in the answer but you should do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297522/android-integer-from-xml-resource

Comment: You trying to do something like this `if(integer >= string)` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert that string to int and then compare it with POS:

```
if(POS >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.lastaricle))){
     Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, R.string.last, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
     POS += 1;
     fillDetails(POS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `integers.xml` for ints ref : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Integer

And then no matter if you use `strings.xml` or `integers.xml` values are generated ints that are reference to i.e. `R.string.lastaricle` or `R.integer.lastaricle` so to get value you need call getter from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources

> if(POS>=getString(R.string.lastaricle))
>
> if(POS>=getResources().getString(R.string.mess_1))
>
> if(POS>=this.getString(R.string.resource_name))

Those didn't work cause you compared `String` with `Integer`

**integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="lastaricle">5</integer>
</resources>
```

```
    if (POS >= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.lastaricle)) {
        Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, R.string.lastaricle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        POS += 1;
        fillDetails(POS);
    }
```