# Android Vector Using Custom Resource Values (e.g. int, float)

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way to outsource values for xml sheets with a custom resource file holding floats/integers? It's a huge pain manually tweaking things such as stroke values for a mass amount of vector elements.

Example:

`android:strokeWidth="@custom_resource/stroke_size"`

As opposed to hard coding the same value every time like so:

`android:strokeWidth="0.1"`

Comment: Check this if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297523/11855654

Comment: This is a bit different from my problem since it's strictly XML related and not being done programmatically. I'm trying to see if there is way to replicate the functionality of using "@color/name" or a similar way of referencing values strictly between XML files. Even if I could generate the vector programmatically, it would defeat the entire point of what I want to accomplish.